# Cap aborted SSHKit error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, digital-ocean, sshkit

I am trying to deploy my rails app with capistrano and I am getting the following error after the command:

```
cap production deploy
```

Output:

```
DEBUG[a3e9636c] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rvm ] on handco-op.com
DEBUG[a3e9636c] Command: [ -d ~/.rvm ]
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host appname.com: Authentication failed for user deploy@appname.com
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:219:in `start'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `call'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `create_new_entry'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:22:in `checkout'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:179:in `with_ssh'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:131:in `block in _execute'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `tap'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `_execute'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:62:in `test'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/rvm-dc35ec5e7a74/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user deploy@appname.com
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:219:in `start'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `call'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `create_new_entry'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:22:in `checkout'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:179:in `with_ssh'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:131:in `block in _execute'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `tap'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `_execute'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:62:in `test'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/rvm-dc35ec5e7a74/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => rvm:hook
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Just to be clear, I replaced my real server name with "appname" to stay secret;) Thanks for any advice! I hope it is a simple fix and I will keep looking into the error as well.

Comment: Just hit something similar on `cap deploy`
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@clore/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit.rb:35: undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 1):

I was missing secret keys, had to set up nopassword ssh and a lot of other tweaks.  It is a hard error to fix and takes a lot of things to get around.  It was about three hours of debugging and fixing my permissions.  Some tutorials setting this up actually can mess things up such as setting the users in the sudo group really makes it hard to define the user directly in: visudo  I recommend not adding anything to the sudo group via:

```
sudo adduser user sudo
```

This was just my set up so you may need to add a user to sudo but I prefer giving ALL permissions to my users in visudo with:

```
visudo

user ALL = NOPASSWD:
```

Hope this someone get around this! it was a dang hard error to fix with a lot happening and was mostly my user errors when configuring capistrano. Good luck! Keep calm and code on!;)